# CSS Multiple Backgrounds not working on IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I have the following CSS class defined:

```
.box .login {
    border: 0;
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    height: 48px;
    background: url(../images/submitr.gif) no-repeat right;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 12px 42px 16px 23px;
    margin: 8px 22px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The multiple background are working perfectly on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE9. However, they're not working on IE8. Does anyone know why that is?

(if I only have one background, it DOES work on IE8. It's when I start introducing those other backgrounds that it starts to flip out.)

Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: What do you mean by multiple backgrounds? Are you talking about a sprite based approach, or actually trying to assign 2 backgrounds to one element.

Comment: I don't see any multiple backgrounds in your existing CSS.

Comment: It doens't answer your question, but maybe someone could be interested in a polyfill: http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Multiple Backgrounds is a CSS3 specification. IE8 DOES NOT understand CSS3, <del>and IE9 for that matter doesn't understand it all</del>. To get it to work in older browsers you'll have to combine the images into one, or overlay multiple elements to get them all to display on top of one another. `z-index:` is your friend :-)

Comment: AJMaxwell, thats not right, IE9 supports Multiple Backgrounds fine.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I'm a tad late I guess, but there are ways to have multipe backgrounds with CSS2.1 which work in IE8:

http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/

Comment: very cool, i got it to work!  took some extra help from here http://www.webdesignetc.co/faking-multiple-backgrounds-in-ie8/ but i figured it out, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support CSS 3 multiple backgrounds.