# Two Body Background Images Disappear in IE8

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, background

I have used two images for my body background; one as a gradient accross the top and the other repeated down below/behind it.

It all works exactly how I want - but disappears in IE8!

Css:

```
body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-image: URL('./img/backtop.jpg'), URL('./img/back.jpg') ;
    background-position: top center, top center ;
    background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat ;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Multiple Backgrounds not working on IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045302/css-multiple-backgrounds-not-working-on-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Backgrounds is a CSS3 specification so it's not available in IE8.

[CSS Multiple Backgrounds not working on IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045302/css-multiple-backgrounds-not-working-on-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

That is CSS3 functionality, so it won't work in IE8. It is possible to replicate the functionality with pseudo elements, as [detailed here](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/), but it's probably easiest to combine the images.