# Multiple backgrounds with CSS positioning

Tags: css, background, repeat

how would I go about making this kind of background: i have a 150px x 150px image which I would like to repeat through the whole background. But the very top line (the top 150px) a different image should repeat just on the x axis. And same on the bottom, the bottom line a third image should repeat on the x axis. How would I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out!

```
body {
    bacground: url(topbackground.png) repeat-x, 
               url(bottombackground.png) bottom fixed repeat-x,
               url(centerbackground.png);
}
```

Also, here's a link to an example with a bunch of kitten pictures!

http://jsfiddle.net/7Rt99/

Comment: that, my friend, is a beautiful solution. Thank you!

Comment: Up to now I didn´t know that you could assign more than one background to one layer. Do you know how that´s supported on IE 8? I could only try IE 9 - that seems to work

Comment: @cljk [It doesn't look like IE 8 supports what I'm doing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5045357), but [this](http://nicolasgallagher.com/multiple-backgrounds-and-borders-with-css2/) looks promising for IE8. I have not tried this out though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create 3 different divs for this so that you can repeat each background in separate parts.

```
<div class="two" id="one">
</div>
<div class="two" id="one">
</div>
<div class="two" id="one">
</div>


#one{
background-image:url('http://www.shrtclothing.com/images/share/facebookthumb.jpeg');
    background-image:repeat;
width:1000px;
height:150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hVvdL/

Comment: or just make 2 divs, one for the top and one for the bottom. You can have the middle part the `body` background.

Comment: thank you...how do I make the bottom one always float to the bottom though?

Comment: there's a couple things you can do. Either you can use background x, y as coordinates or you can do a position:absolute;
bottom:0px; .